# can not save react native stringfy data using laravel controller

Tags: reactjs, react-native, laravel-5

**this is the react native code**

```
    fetch('https://sssdff.000webhostapp.com/save/', {
        method: 'post',
        header:{
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({
            name: "john",
            price: 145,

        })

    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) =>{
            alert("sucess");
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            alert("error"+error);
            console.error(error);
        });
```

**This is the laravel code**

```
  public function save(Request $request)
{

    $data = $request->name;

    $coin = new Coin();
    $coin->name=$data;
    $coin->price= 125;
    $coin->save();


 return response()->json([ 'state' => 'success' ]);

}
```

when i pass a string value, like $coin->name="jack"; it successes and save data to database. But when i try to pass parameter value then got a error.

Comment: can you post what the error says?

Comment: try json_decode

Comment: @GustavoTopete  error is json parse error

Answer (score 0):

```
Try directly it will work, do not stringify.
`
body:{
name: "john",
price: 145,
}
`
inside laravel:

`$data = request()->all();
$coin = new Coin();
$coin->name=$data['name'];
$coin->price= $data['price'];
$coin->save();
`
```

Comment: in your code 'Content-Type' , 't' is not capital, it should be capital(upper-case).
and for unsupported body init stringyfy it.
i would suggest you to use axios package it is bit simple, instead of fetch.

Comment: i tried it also. The request is send successfully. But when i access the data from laravel side it will get error.

Comment: can you specific the error of laravel side in detail.

Comment: thanks i got the answer. I had to add csrf token from the laravel side. That was the issue.